# passing structure from c# to C dll

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, structure

I am trying to learn enough C# so that I can pass a strcture by reference to a C DLL; but it never gets to the "cFunction".  As you can see in the cFunction, I am explicitly setting the streamSubset value to 44; but back in the c# portion it does not return "44".
Here is the C code:

```
typedef struct s_mPlot
{
    double      price[100];
    int         streamSubset;
} mPlot;

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )  
void cFunction(mPlot *Mplot){
    Mplot->streamSubset = 44;}
```

// and here is the c# code

```
 using System;
    using Vibe.Function;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class MPLOT 
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
        public double []    price;
        public int          streamSubset;
     } 

namespace Vibe.Indicator{
public class myIdx : IndicatorObject {

    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\joe\\mcDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern void cFunction(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]  MPLOT  mPlot );
    public myIdx(object _ctx):base(_ctx){}
    private IPlotObject plot1;

    protected override void Create()
    {
        MPLOT mPlot         = new MPLOT();
        mPlot.streamSubset = 2; 
        cFunction(mPlot);

        if (mPlot.streamSubset == 44)
             go();  
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please provide more info -- what do you see instead?  Crash?  Unexpected results?  Incorrect data?  Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: The C# code can't run using the debugger.  Long explanation, but it is a commercial product that prevents it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the following:

1. You almost certainly need to specify the `cdecl` calling convention in your `DllImport` attribute. Add `CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl`.
2. I believe that `UnmanagedType.LPStruct` adds an extra level of indirection. But you are passing a C# `class` which is a reference type. That means you are passing a pointer to a pointer. That's one level of indirection too many. First of all remove `[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]` altogether. Then your code should work. If you switched to a struct rather than a class for `MPLOT` then you'd need to pass by `ref` to get the indirection.

I think I would have the code like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MPLOT 
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
    public double []    price;
    public int          streamSubset;
} 

[DllImport("dllname.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void cFunction(
    ref MPLOT mPlot
);
```

Comment: No, what you suggest does not work either.  I cannot find any examples of this on the Web after searching thru dozens of pages...starting to think it can't be done.

Comment: The code in this answer definitely matches the C++ code in your question. Write yourself a little C++ DLL to prove that is so. Something that we can't see is wrong here. What you are trying to do, to marshal this struct is trivially easy to achieve.

Comment: I did what you suggested, and you are right.  What I discovered is that there is a bug in the 3rd party app that is causing the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the calling convention explicitly:

```
 [DllImport("C:\\Users\\joe\\mcDll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
```

VC exports with calling convention `cdecl` by default, but `DllImport` uses `stdcall` by default. So you have to specify at least one of them explicitly, or better, both.

Comment: Tried adding that, and I get this cryptic message (from the commercial product, not vs2010): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @user994179 That is weird. Then i think you need to use stdcall on your C++ Dll.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]` with `ref`.

Comment: OK, so it now reads: "public static extern void cFunction( ref    MPLOT mPlot )"   I also had to add "ref" keyword to the param list where I call cFunction:  "cFunction(ref mPlot)".  Still same error: "Object ref not set to an instance of an object."